# RabbitMQ at SSL port 5671 not accessible, but accessible on telnet

Tags: c#, ssl, rabbitmq

I am trying to connect to RabbitMQ on remote machine by using SSL (development ssl create for localhost). I am using EasyNetQ and I followed every procedure about the regsitration an configuration of the certificate (https://liquidwarelabs.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019562832-Disable-cleartext-authentication-option-in-RabbitMQ). The idea is to "fix" AMPQ Cleartext Authentication issue (reported by some security tool). Also I've installed the .pfx certificate as trusted on both machines.

By the end of this procedure, the RabbitMQ is transferred to TLS protocol (even the management plugin), and by trying on telnet the port 5671 is open and accessible on the remote machine. However the following code returns error: None of the specified endpoints were reachable (message in caught DoNothingLogger)

```
                    var connection = new ConnectionConfiguration();

                    connection.Port = 5671;
                    connection.UserName = "admin";
                    connection.Password = "****";
                    connection.Product = "localhost";
                    connection.VirtualHost = "StageDev";


                    var host1 = new HostConfiguration();
                    host1.Host = "skl-igor-naum1";
                    host1.Port = 5671;
                    host1.Ssl.Enabled = true;
                    host1.Ssl.ServerName = "localhost";
                    host1.Ssl.CertPath = "C:\\tmp\\ProfileUnity.pfx";                        
                    //host1.Ssl.CertPassphrase = "admin";
                    ////host1.Ssl.Version = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11;


                    connection.Hosts = new List<HostConfiguration> { host1 };

                    connection.Validate();




                    MessageBusConnection = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(connection, services => services.Register<IEasyNetQLogger>(logger => new DoNothingLogger()));
```

Does anyone had similar problem or knows the solution ?

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

#EasyNetQ 3.5.1

```
private ConnectionConfiguration GetConnectionConfiguration(ushort prefetchCount)
    {
                var cnn = new ConnectionConfiguration
                {
                    Name = "111.1.1.11",/*rabbitmq ip*/
                    VirtualHost = "/",
                    UserName = "user",
                    Password = "pass",
                    PrefetchCount = prefetchCount,
                    Port = 5671
                };
    
                var host = new HostConfiguration
                {
                    Host = "111.1.1.11",/*rabbitmq ip*/,
                    Port = 5671
                };
    
                host.Ssl.AcceptablePolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable;
                host.Ssl.Enabled = true;
                host.Ssl.Version = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls;
                host.Ssl.ServerName = "111.1.1.11",/*rabbitmq ip*/;
    
                cnn.Hosts = new List<HostConfiguration> { host };
                
                return cnn ;
    }
```

**create bus**

```
    var mybus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(GetConnectionConfiguration(1), x =>
     {
         x.Register<IConventions, AttributeBasedConventions>();
         x.EnableMessageVersioning();
     });
```

[see reuslt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65H10.png)

IsConnected = true

[Rabbitmq ssl/tls status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtogU.png)